# How to bind the docker container and the cuba process through localhost:9292 in Ubuntu 14

Tags: ruby, docker, jruby, docker-compose, cuba

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and I have a super simple Cuba App which seems to be lacking something:

***Gemfile:***

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'cuba'
```

***config.ru***

```
require "./hello_world"
run Cuba
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "9292:9292"
  command: bundle exec rackup -p 9292
```

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM jruby:1.7.19

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD . /myapp

RUN bundle install
```

I've tryed to run it through the `docker-compose up`. Which builds the image and binds me the cuba process in the terminal. I can see the server listening to the port 9292. But I'm totally unable to access it through the `localhost:9292` url.

Comment: Are you using boot2docker?

Comment: No, running on ubuntu 14. I was able to run a rails app.

Comment: Ok, what about if you do `docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash` then try accessing localhost:9292 with curl, does that work? (Replace CONTAINER with the name of your container)

Comment: No, I wasn't able to do it. I think the host is not binded. Gonna check the rackup help.

Comment: Ok, but then I would have expected you would have been able to access the port from inside the container...

Comment: I wasn't the container was not binded to any IP. I had to bind it to the host 0.0.0.0. I'm not still able to understand what's going on in the backstage. Any addition to my answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok. I don't know ruby well enough to comment. I would have expected it to bind to127.0.0.1 by default. 0.0.0.0 listens to all interfaces, so that's why that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like by default the host is not binded to the docker daemon ip. Changing the docker-compose.yml and adding the rackup option fixed it.

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "9292:9292"
  command: bundle exec rackup -o 0.0.0.0
```